# How can I output specific elements in this php array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using Gravity Forms for WordPress and one of the form elements is a List item that can have multiple entries. I have a page on the website that I am building that will output the data from this item onto the page but I am having trouble accessing the actual items from the array.

This is the code I am using to retrieve the array:

```
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
$key = 'my_playlist';
$single = false;

$my_playlist = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single );
print_r(array_values($my_playlist));
```

The output I get from this looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:10:"Song Title";s:15:"test song title";s:11:"Song Artist";s:16:"test song artist";}i:1;a:2:{s:10:"Song Title";s:11:"test song 2";s:11:"Song Artist";s:13:"test artist 2";}} )
```

So far I have tried to access the elements like this:

```
foreach($my_playlist as $item){
    echo 'Item: ' . $item[0] . '<br />';
}
```

but it only outputs `Item: a`

I would like to output it like:

**Song Title:** test song title  **Song Artist:** test song artist

**Song Title:** test song 2      **Song Artist:** test artist 2

How do I access each element in this array? Also, what type of array is this? It might help me track down how to access the required items.

Comment: please take a look at this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

Comment: Looks like serialized data, so use `unserialize` on it before accessing values.

Comment: Thanks @Jules for the link however the table I need to access is this one http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) your array:

```
$my_wake_playlist = unserialize($my_wake_playlist);
```

and you'll have your PHP array back.

Comment: Thanks, this has saved me heaps of time. To get it to serialize the array in my case I had to use my_wake_playlist = unserialize($my_wake_playlist[0]);

Answer (score 2):

This string:

```
a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:10:"Song Title";s:15:"test song title";s:11:"Song Artist";s:16:"test song artist";}i:1;a:2:{s:10:"Song Title";s:11:"test song 2";s:11:"Song Artist";s:13:"test artist 2"
```

is serialized. Use unserialize function to decode it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It pointed me in the right direction.